# Comparing Desktop and documents with their backup and produce an output.txt file that highlights the different folders and files between them

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, compareobject

can someone please help me. Still new to powershell, I am comparing my documents and desktop mirror to check my backup solutions using several different codes. The one below is meant to check both the documents/desktop with its mirror folders and tell me exactly what files are 'different' between source and destination and output it into the same output.txt file (not sure if it overwrites it). When I do this for my documents alone, it works when I want try the code for my desktop it doesn't output anything at all. Any advice?

```
function Get-Directories ($path)
{
    $PathLength = $path.length
    Get-ChildItem $path -exclude *.pst,*.ost,*.iso,*.lnk | % {
        Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name RelativePath -Value $_.FullName.substring($PathLength+1)
        $_
    }
}

Compare-Object (Get-Directories $Folder3) (Get-Directories $Folder4) -Property RelativePath | Sort RelativePath, Name -desc | Out-File  C:\Users\desktop\output.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by earlier revisions of your question, your problem wasn't that your code didn't output *anything at all*, but that the output *had empty `Name` property values*.

Thus, **the only thing missing from your code was [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object)'s `-PassThru` switch**:

```sh
Compare-Object -PassThru (Get-Directories $Folder3) (Get-Directories $Folder4) -Property RelativePath | 
  Sort RelativePath, Name -desc | 
    Out-File C:\Users\desktop\output.txt
```

*Without* `-PassThru`, `Compare-Object` outputs `[pscustomobject]` instances that have a `.SideIndicator` property (to indicate which side a difference object is exclusive to) *and only the comparison properties passed to `-Property`*.

- That is, in your original attempt the `Compare-Object` output objects had *only* `.SideIndicator` and `.RelativePath` properties, and none of the other properties of the original `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances originating from `Get-ChildItem`, such as `.Name`, `.LastWriteTime`, ...

*With* `-PassThru`, the *original* objects are passed through, decorated with an ETS (Extended Type System) `.SideIndicator` property (decorated in the same way you added the `.RelativePath` property), accessing the `.Name` property later works as intended.

Note:

- Since `Out-File` then receives the full (and decorated) `[System.IO.FileInfo]` instances, you may want to limit what properties get written via a [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) call beforehand.
  Additionally you may choose a *structured* output format, via [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) for instance, given that the formatting that [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) applies is meant only for the human observer, not for programmatic processing.
- `$_.FullName.substring($PathLength+1)` in your `Get-Directories` should be `$_.FullName.substring($PathLength)`, otherwise you'll cut off the 1st char.

Answer (score 1):

since you're not using `-Recurse` when listing files, you could just use the file name instead of adding on a relative path property:

```sh
$folder1 = gci 'C:\Users\username\desktop' -exclude *.pst,*.ost,*.iso,*.lnk
$folder2 = gci 'D:\desktop' -exclude *.pst,*.ost,*.iso,*.lnk
Compare-Object $folder1 $folder2 -Property Name,Length

Name     Length SideIndicator
----     ------ -------------
test.txt    174 =>           
test.csv    174 <=           

# Alternatively, use -PassThru to keep the whole object:
Compare-Object $folder1 $folder2 -Property Name,Length -PassThru | select SideIndicator,FullName,Length,LastWriteTime

SideIndicator FullName                  Length LastWriteTime       
------------- --------                  ------ -------------       
=>            D:\desktop                   174 7/14/2021 2:47:09 PM
<=            C:\Users\username\desktop    174 7/14/2021 2:47:09 PM
```

Use `Out-File -Append` to append output to a file.

---

As for troubleshooting your current script, try manually checking whether the RelativePath property looks like it's getting set correctly for you:

```
(Get-Directories $Folder3).RelativePath
(Get-Directories $Folder4).RelativePath
```

Finally, I recommend using robocopy over powershell for backup stuff like this, since it can use backup privileges (for locked files) and can copy multiple files at a time, but it's personal preference:

> ```text
> robocopy source destination /b /mir /mt /r:0 /w:0
>
> /b - Runs robocopy in backup mode. Will copy everything as long as you are an Administrator
> /mir - Mirrors everything from the source to the destination
> /mt - Copies up to 8 files at a time
> /r:0 - Sets it to not retry a file, default is like a million retries
> /w:0 - Sets the time to 0 seconds between retries - default is like 30 seconds
> ```
>
> source: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/286190-transfer-user-profiles-using-robocopy

Comment: thank you so so much I will give this a go tonight, sorry where does the out-file -append go into the script? do you pipe it in at the end | Out-File -Path -Append like this?

Comment: @Yaz yeah: `$stuff | Out-File -Path 'C:\path\to\output.txt' -Encoding utf8 -Append`